# Why has my Facebook application stopped working?

Tags: php, facebook

I have two applications with two canvas urls:
1. [apps.facebook.com/walnuts-album](http://apps.facebook.com/walnuts-album)
2. [apps.facebook.com/walnuts](http://apps.facebook.com/walnuts)

Today I updated the urls of the second one two reach my server (same urls as the first app), little after I changed it both of the apps stopped to work for new users (for me it's working but not for anyone else).

Anyone knows what is all about? (and how can I fix this).

Comment: Are you sure your app is not in sandbox mode?

Comment: sure...look at the screenshot
http://screensnapr.com/v/rH9C33.png

Comment: another thing is that the both apps working for me and for old users that used the app before, but not for new users. weird....

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/advanced

There is Sandbox Mode. Turn it OFF, because in sandbox mode it'S only accessible for developers

Comment: @Oren did you note "Changes saved. Note that your changes may take several minutes to propagate to all servers" ?

Comment: of curse but something very odd happened, after I saved the changes it didn't work only in the new app (192 error code) but after couple of minutes it worked in both apps, and than, after an hour everything stopped work (both apps).

I think maybe facebook think this is spamy apps because i linked both apps to the same source...:/